# Uisng A/MX records instead of NS for hosting and emails

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting

I have registered a .ma (moroccan TLD). I have a web hosting setuped at Godaddy. The issue that im having is i would like to host my site with godaddy and use outlook.com for creating emails. Unfortunately when i sent the Godaddy nameservers and the mx records generated by outlook to my domain registrar company, they said its not possible to set both NS and A/MX records. so i have the choice of either NS or A/MX records

as far as i know NS are required to point to the hosting. Can someone guide me on how can i setup the hosting and email using A/MX records instead of NS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their support is horrible and has confused you about a very basic concept.  Shame on them.

Of course you can have all kinds of RRtypes.  The only constraint commonly encountered is that `CNAME` and `DNAME` records for a name cannot coexist with any other RRtype, including each other.  You can (and generally will) have NS and A and MX records for your base domain.

What they mean is that, if you want to use their DNS service to set your A and MX and whatever other records up, you cannot also specify your own nameservers; you must use theirs (obviously, because they are hosting DNS for you).  If you want to run your own nameservers, create glue records if you don't already have them, and set your nameservers for your domain to your own.  Then, you can create the A and MX and other records yourself (instead of using their interface and service for it).  The same goes for using any other DNS provider.

If you want to use their hosted DNS you do not need your own NS records.  However, if they are any good (I have always hosted my own DNS), they will still allow you to set up NS records for subdomains, which is how you delegate them.

The only thing an NS record really does is points at the DNS servers used to get other records for your domain.  So, in a way, it must point at your **DNS** hosting, but not necessarily at where your services are hosted.